# Subsets of Sample space that are not events

Tags: probability-theory

In VK Rohatgi,  It is written that all the subset of uncountable sample space is not an event . And also it is not easy to find one that is not event
please define which type of subsets in sample space that are not events

Comment: How much probability theory do you know?

Comment: I just start learning

Comment: You need measure theory to understand the Vitali set anyway : fair enough you accepted the answer below but you need to understand how things work beforee you see why that is a non-event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A famous counter-example is the Vitali set : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set